# Joomla 1.5 administrator module description

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I have developed a module for the administration backend of Joomla 1.5. The description is language based like the example shows below:

```
MODULE_DESCRIPTION=This is the description of the module
```

Once the module has installed, the description for some reason shows as MODULE_DESCRIPTION but when I view it in the module manager, then it shows correctly. Im not sure why on earth this is happening. It cant be an error in my code seeing as it does show properly in the module manager.

Could there possibly be a bug within the language based descriptions upon installation?

Comment: "It cant be an error in my code" Yes it can

Comment: all I have done is used a language file and the xml, and seeing as this is the case, there is nothing that could be wrong in the code to make it work in the module manager and not upon installation. They come from the same source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Joomla 1.5 I don't think you need the underscore(s) but I'm not sure whether that is the cause of the language lookup during installation - more likely the point I raise below.

The two most useful references for language files I can find are:
http://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files  (for all Joomla versions)
http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_language_definition_file (for 1.5 only)

One potential problem is that during the installation process Joomla looks for a .sys.ini file for language translations, whereas in normal use it uses the .ini file. Modules though don't use .sys.ini files - or at least I don't see mention of them anywhere in the documentation for module building in J1.5

Comment: I tried without the underscore but no hope. I did a little test and changed client="administrator" to client="site" and reinstalled it and the description upon installation works but when I use client="administrator", it doesnt.